# Why does "Temporary page!" error occur?

Tags: document-configuration

At the end my document, I get a new page that contains,

```
Temporary page!

LATEX was unable to guess the total number of pages correctly.
As there was some unprocessed data that should have been
added to the final page this extra page has been added to
receive it.

If you rerun the document (without altering it) this surplus
page will go away, because LATEX now knows how many pages
to expect for this document.
```

I know that by just recompiling the document, I can get rid of this error, but I was wondering why does this occur and what unprocessed data that LaTeX couldn't process. For citations, table of contents, table and figure references, LaTeX needs to be run twice, but I have never ever seen this "Temporary page!" page before.

Comment: It is not an error but needed for some lastpage hook code where latex needs to know the number of pages

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Was it introduced recently?  I'm pretty sure I didn't see it in older versions of TeX.

Comment: yes it came with the latex shipout hooks, see `texdoc ltshipout`.